# Multivariable Calculus Vector Fields

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

I have to prove that if 
$f(x,y,z)=f_{a}(x,y,z)+f_b(x,y,z)+f_c(x,y,z)$ is a conservative vector field and and $g(x,y,z)=g_{a}(x,y,z)+g_b(x,y,z)+g_c(x,y,z)$ is also a conservative vector field, then $(cf+dg)(x,y,z)$ is conservative.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say prove that it is also conservative just for clarification.

Comment: While you're editing, do you mean $f = (f_a,f_b,f_c)$? These should be vector-valued functions. Here's a hint: What does *conservative* mean? Write that down for each of $f$ and $g$ and see if you can deduce what you want for $cf+dg$.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if they are real valued functions it would change the nature of the answer because then I think it becomes a proof of curl(f)+curl(g)=curl(f+g), which is easy enough to prove.